# Scala: Conditional Actor Chaining

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have two actors A and B.
A Controller sends a request to actor A. Now actor A return a response of type `Try[AbcResponse]`. `AbcResponse` being a case class here.
Actor A based on some logic might directly return this response or it might conditionally call another actor B using ask. After manipulating the response from B it would then send the response of type `Try[AbcResponse]` to the controller.

So what should i do in my actor A to handle this situation. I do not want to put a await in my actor A because that would waste the thread pool and cause slowdowns in the system. How can i efficiently handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the sender reference in a message to actor B and [`pipe`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/futures.html#use-with-actors) the response from actor B to `self`. Obviously actor B in its response would have to pass this reference back to actor A.

```
import akka.pattern.{ask, pipe}

case class MsgToActorB(..., target: ActorRef)
case class ResponseFromActorB(..., target: ActorRef)

class ActorA extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case r: Request =>
      val s = sender
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
      // do something with the request
      if (someCondition)
        s ! Try(AbcResponse(...))
      else
        (actorB ? MsgToActorB(..., s)).mapTo[ResponseFromActorB].pipeTo(self)

    case ResponseFromActorB(..., target) =>
      // do something with the response from B and send a response to the original sender
      target ! Try(AbcResponse(...))
  }
}
```

While the above approach is safe, it'd be simpler to not use `ask` as shown below. If you must use `ask` and if actor B is blocking when it processes a message from actor A, then consider configuring a separate dispatcher as described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management).

```
def receive = {
  case r: Request =>
    val s = sender
    // do something with the request
    if (someCondition)
      s ! Try(AbcResponse(...))
    else
      actorB ! MsgToActorB(..., s)

  case ResponseFromActorB(..., target) =>
    // do something with the response from B and send a response to the original sender
    target ! Try(AbcResponse(...))
}
```

Comment: In this situation is it bad to put a callback in the actor itself after calling actor B using ask?

Comment: @Sidhant: Using `mapTo` and `pipeTo` (which are not callbacks) with `ask` is a common pattern, as mentioned [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future) and in other parts of the documentation.